# Term describes the feeling of weariness or boredom

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What do you call the state of **tiredness or lack of interest**. It is subtly different from ordinary boredom.  A feeling like "*the world is so boring*"but just a little different, implying that the state of weariness is a result of too many encounters with others.
There is an exact term but I can't remember it.

Comment: I was going to answer this, but was suddenly overcome by a sense of apathy and ennui, so I took a nap instead.

Comment: @Hot Licks, I'm (*vaguely*) aware of a (*purportedly*) effective herbal remedy for the treatment of such existential ailments - what state are you currently in?

Comment: @LittleEva - A state of utter confusion.  (No, wait -- that's Wisconsin.  I guess we're only a little confused by comparison.)

Comment: @Hot Licks, Wisconsin? Never mind, with that governor of yours that remedy I spoke of is light-years from you, I think your stuck with the apathy and ennui. Go back to your nap.

Comment: Light-years? A three hour drive and I got ya covered, bro.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A good noun describing such a state is *ennui*.

> [**ennui**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=ennui+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=ennui+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l5j41.0.0.1.4852452...........0.csjsD8_PBEM&gws_rd=ssl) *noun*: a feeling of listlessness and dissatisfaction arising from a lack of occupation or excitement.
>
> *synonyms*: boredom, tedium, listlessness, lethargy, lassitude, languor, weariness, enervation
> (Google)

Comment: +1...This would have been my first choice and then "doldrums"

Comment: Ennui and lethargy would have been my choices too!

Comment: This YouTube video of a cat speaking French is, I believe, the perfect accompaniment to this answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0M7ibPk37_U

Comment: Thanks @Mari-Lou, really enjoyed Henri, who happens to be a long-haired version of my own pampered, tuxedo-clad feline, Sissy (whose real name is Richard – I was confused as to her gender – now she’s the one confused!). Additionally, the soundtrack which accompanies the sad, disaffected Henri is the third of Erik Satie’s [Gymnopedie 1, 2, 3 (After The Rain)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWbsEoqO4K0), (arranged/interpreted by Pascal Rogé) ...

Comment: http://www.word-detective.com/2010/03/gymnopedie/ Everything's more easy when you have a keyboard and an Internet connection....*sigh*. Nope, not seen *Man on Wire*

Comment: Hi! No, I'm afraid not.  The movie has fully loaded, and I've tried everything to save the file, but I keep getting error 404. If you don't delete the Google link, which I have saved, I'll be able to see the movie whenever I'm in the mood. :)

Comment: 'Ennui' has extra class because Cole Porter used it in 'I Get A Kick Out Of You' ["... fighting vainly the old ennui..."]

Answer (score 15):

**[Jaded](https://www.google.com/search?q=jaded)** perhaps

> adjective
>  bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had
>   too much of something.

(Google)

or **[World-Weary](https://www.google.com/search?q=world%20weary%20definition)**

> adjective
>  feeling or indicating feelings of weariness, boredom, or
>   cynicism as a result of long experience of life.

(Google)

Comment: It can be but there's a certain word of "world-weariness", but just a little different.

Comment: Hey there @LittleEva . Thank you. And +1 to you too.

Comment: @JaegerJay +1 for *world-weariness*, I don't see how *ennui* captures this at all.

Comment: @Mazura When i searched the word "ennui", it says there almost the same definition I have described in the OP. World-weariness is included there :).

Comment: *world-weary* is usually hyphenated, Avon. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva But you've already up-voted it. I don't see that there's any incentive for me to correct it now.

Comment: Ha-ha. You're a hard case, Avon!

Comment: @LittleEva I am but ...go on then. Just this once.

Comment: Oh no, not me, it's entirely up to your discretion.

Comment: @LittleEva I have no discretion. I am totally reliant on other people's.

Comment: @RemarkLima Thank you. I presume you meant "tastes". In fact I hope you meant that. TMI otherwise.

Comment: @Avon that has to be my top auto correct error of all time! Still, maybe it's true when they say men think with their **** ;-)

Comment: @RemarkLima I am so relieved to hear that. That makes it the funniest thing I've seen in a long while. Thank you and your auto correct.

Comment: Lol! I'm now more concerned about my auto correct!

Comment: @RemarkLima, that autocorrect of yours has some twisted testes!

Comment: "remarklima was starting to feel rather jaded with everyone examining his use of his testes"  ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Ennui, boredom, tedium,  and ***doldrums***- are *comparable* when they denote a state of dissatisfaction and weariness.

> [**doldrums**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/purpose)
>
> Use this noun to describe a period of time that is boring, depressing,
>   or characterized by inactivity.
>
> - The noun doldrums is derived from the word dull. If you’ve been vegging out in front of the TV for hours, bored out of your mind, you
>     might say you’re "**in the doldrums**."

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/purpose))

Doldrums applies to a phase or period of depression that may be marked by listness, despondency and flagging enery.

([MW dictionary of synonyms](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA437&dq=ineluctable&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sMCjVeSmEceXuATG-rywBw&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=ennui&f=false))

Comment: +1, *doldrums* is like the informal sibling of ennui.

Comment: Never heard of doldrum before.

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for **"apathy"**?

> - apathy - (noun) lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern. [Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=wowser+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=K2WyVe6XJY2vzQLnu4v4BQ&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=apathy+definition)

or **"insipidity"** (noun) - the state of finding everything uninteresting and dull.

**boredom**, **tedium**, **uninterestedness** and **unconcern** may also apply.

Answer (score 4):

[Blasé](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blase) may suggest the idea:

> - indifferent to something because of familiarity or surfeit,
> - lacking enthusiasm; bored

(Collins)

Comment: Nope, I mean it is a subtle change of mood for no apparent reason. Not exhausted because of over-activity.

Comment: Sort of subtle feeling of depression?

Comment: Yeah, somewhat similar too that. But I won't consider it a depression because these feelings come and go with no clear precipitant.

Answer (score 3):

**Insouciant** is also a great word for this

> showing a casual lack of concern; indifferent.

Sylvia Plath has a poem called Ennui that is littered with all kinds of these words (of course the word ennui itself being the most prominent)

Answer (score 2):

How about *anhedonia*? The [*Concise Oxford English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sYScAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22inability+to+feel+pleasure+in+normally+pleasurable+activities%22&source=bl&ots=nWcIWnK_5a&sig=sqQEHl6I3dHTo5XDEE8RMNZ1LFc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIgYrm4_X1xgIVSi-ICh1hiwKc#v=onepage&q=%22inability%20to%20feel%20pleasure%20in%20normally%20pleasurable%20activities%22&f=false) defines this as

> inability to feel pleasure in normally pleasurable activities.

Comment: I added a in-text citation and a link to a dictionary that uses the exact wording you quoted. I also removed the attribution to Google, since that is not a helpful source to cite.

Answer (score 2):

## Malaise

> ma·laise
> məˈlāz/
> noun
> noun: malaise; plural noun: malaises
> a general feeling of discomfort, illness, or uneasiness whose exact cause is difficult to identify.
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/malaise)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your accepted answer and nearly all the others are synonyms for *boredom*. I shall tackle the part everyone missed (*jaded* comes close): *"implying that the state of weariness is a result of too many encounters with others."*

Not a single word, but I describe this as *'being on'* and wish I could *'turn off'*. Introverts like myself, might have about two hours tolerance for engaging other people. After that we need to collect ourselves.

> *I'm tired of **being on** all day, I need some time to myself.*

It's the heightened level of consciousness required, for acceptable social interaction, that makes us so weary.

> *Thank god all my guests went home. I'm mentally exhausted. Finally, I can **turn off***.

Answer (score -3):

Depression:

> Feelings of sadness, tearfulness, emptiness or hopelessness
>   <sub>[Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/symptoms-causes/syc-20356007)</sub>