# Word for the situation wherein you lose interest in life due to boredom

Tags: single-word-requests

Do we have any word to describe the situation wherein you lose interest in life not due to tragedies but boredom and you want to quit life because nothing mundane or spiritual brings joy to you?

Comment: That sounds like [depression](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/depression/expert-answers/clinical-depression/faq-20057770) to me....

Comment: @Hellion Depression is an umbrella terminology which describes all suicidal thoughts. I want something very specific to what i hv asked.

Comment: _Life. Don't talk to me about life..._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Term describes the feeling of weariness or boredom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262108/term-describes-the-feeling-of-weariness-or-boredom)

Comment: Cheer up, always look at the bright side of life... no, seriously, please seek professional advice if this is your true feelings.

Comment: Hey, nothing like dat is a issue wid me. I am writing some fiction, so needed something of this sorted. Bdw thanks a lot for the concern.

Comment: Hi chimophilic and welcome to S.E. We have certain requirements of Single Word Requests, and one of them is to write a context in which you might use the word. This helps us to select the best choice by allowing us to know the necessary degree of formality, the part part of speech required (e.g. adjective, noun) and which connotations are suitable or unsuitable to what you want to communicate. It also gives us a reason to believe such a word may be useful enough to exist. Would you please add this information for us, so that we know what to suggest and how to vote upon submitted suggestions?

Comment: Is the part about wanting to quit life mandatory?  None of the answers so far include that.

Answer (score 46):

Ennui:

> a feeling of listlessness and dissatisfaction arising from a lack of occupation or excitement.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ennui)</sub>

Comment: You're quoting from a dictionary so your answer must include attribution and use quote formatting to indicate it is a direct quote.

Comment: Ennui is an interesting suggestion.  It is a highly literary term in English.  In fact, of course, it is a 'loan word' from the French word for boredom.  I suspect that its use has been declining in frequency for some time, at least in British English, and possibly even more so in British English.

Comment: Assuming a general audience, this is an awful choice. Most people are just going to be confused if you don't explain (or be forced to look in a dictionary).

Comment: @jpmc26: Really?  Though originally a loanword, I’d have thought most moderately well-read English-speakers would understand *ennui* — certainly many more than would recognise *anhedonia* or *acedia*, and probably more than would know *weltschmerz* either, to compare with a few other answers.

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, if the bar is that low, the written word itself is going to confuse people. "Grok no idea what do. Bored"

Comment: @jpmc26 I have to agree with PLL here. _Ennui_ is marked as formal or literary to me, but it is certainly not a word I would expect to be unfamiliar to a general adult audience. I probably wouldn’t be likely to use it in children’s or YA literature, but in fiction aimed at adult readers, I would use it with no qualms.

Comment: +1 It's the word that jumped to mind immediately, and is quite appropriate.

Comment: This is the FANCY way to say it. A lot of the other suggestions given here are good too.

Answer (score 10):

In psychology, the specific symptom of depression that you describe is **anhedonia**.

> Anhedonia is the inability to feel pleasure. It's a common symptom of depression as well as other mental health disorders.

[WebMD link](https://www.webmd.com/depression/what-is-anhedonia#1)

The link has more specifics.

Comment: add a citation to enhance your answer

Comment: That is only half of the question. The OP specifically described, "you want to quit life", and such suicidal thoughts are not implied by the "inability to feel pleasure".

Comment: @whatroughbeast True, but anhedonia is a symptom of major depression for which suicidal ideation is also a symotom. Anhedoni is much more severe and pervasive than just not enjoying things in the way that depression os more than just a little down. It is the word that jumped into my head, especially after the OP’s comment on his question. Of course this is not Medical SE.

Answer (score 9):

world-weary(adj.) or world-weariness(noun)

> Tired of or bored with life, often with a negative or jaded
> attitude.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/world-weary)
>
> Feeling or indicating feelings of weariness, boredom, or cynicism as a
> result of long experience of life.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/world-weary)
>
> feeling or showing fatigue from or boredom with the life of the world
> and especially material pleasures
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world-weary)
>
> no longer finding pleasure in living; tired of the world
> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/world-weary)

Answer (score 9):

The Germans always have the best words in such cases (here in a literary context)

> Weltschmerz, (German: “world grief”) the prevailing mood of melancholy and pessimism associated with the poets of the Romantic era that arose from their refusal or inability to adjust to those realities of the world that they saw as destructive of their right to subjectivity and personal freedom—a phenomenon thought to typify Romanticism.

https://www.britannica.com/art/Weltschmerz

By the way, Schmerz can be translated as "pain", so "world pain" is a direct translation.

Edit: see also http://mentalfloss.com/article/58230/how-tell-whether-youve-got-angst-ennui-or-weltschmerz

Comment: I don't quite agree. *Weltschmerz* as used in English refers to disenchantment, an impatience with the world as it is as opposed to how it might be. It is dejection, not boredom, arising from sentimentality, not jadedness.

Comment: @choster: ennui might be a better word for the OP but I think Weltschmerz could be considered.

Answer (score 4):

You could be describing **acedia** or **accedie.**

> A host of psychological symptoms can signify the presence of acedia, which affects the mental state and behavior of the afflicted. Some commonly reported psychological signs revolve around a lack of attention to daily tasks and an overall dissatisfaction with life. The best-known of the psychological signs of acedia is tedium, boredom or general laziness.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acedia)

Comment: Why are you answering questions which don't meet the clearly defined community standards? What's the point of having any if even the mods don't adhere to them? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

"[Malaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaise)" is a bit stronger in negative connotation, almost to the point of sickness, but could also act nearly as a synonym to ennui [in @james-m answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/485578/319763).

Answer (score 1):

**Apathy**

> lack of interest, or the attitude of not caring resulting from it

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/apathy)

**Apathetic**

> showing no interest or energy and unwilling to take action, especially over something important

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/apathy)

Comment: "lose interest in life" : *depression*. "due to boredom" : *apathy*

Answer (score 0):

[**Anomie**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomie). It refers to a failure of the external “norms” that guide a person’s life, as opposed to their internal emotional or intellectual state.

You are without joy, for example, because the actions that you previously took to achieve a joyful state are no longer working. Your spiritual practice does not bring you to an emotional state of transcendence.

At the same time, there is still the possibility that other actions or other practices might succeed. You have failed, perhaps, but it’s not just you. The people around you that *should* be providing the norms for you to follow have also failed. Or perhaps the failure is one of connection as opposed to a failure of individuals.

*Anomie* is not a commonly used word. However, that can be an advantage, since better-known terms like *apathy* or *ennui* tend to come with meanings already established in the reader’s mind.